# Download files from gear s2

Tags: samsung-gear-s2

I have an application for Samsung Gear S which writes data on its internal memory - simply creates a file in the Documents folder and saves the data into it. When I connect the device to my computer (which has to be a Windows machine), I can copy the file on my computer and work with it.

Now I would like to test the same application on Gear S2; however, since there is no USB connection, I am not sure if there is any other way to transfer the created files to my computer. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can try to do this by following the steps below:

1. At first try connecting Gear s2 with your computer using sdb connect command.(I used the sdb packaged with the tizen sdk tools) Please go through [this link](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000251L).
2. After that try pulling the files from Gear s2 to your development machine
   applying sdb pull command. Please go through [this link](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tools/common-tools/smart-development-bridge) for more details.